# Preview site without cache?

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I have a Wordpress site on a self-hosted domain. There is no cache plugins. I am using Firefox.

When I make changes to the CSS it can sometimes take hours for anything to change in the browser.

I use Plesk and its the same in the Plesk preview so the trick with a random hash and query doesn't work either.

How to solve this please? I need to see live changes please.

Comment: just use incognito mode or clear cache on firefox

Answer (score 3):

try use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>  to hard refresh your browser

Comment: In 2018, maybe it's different, but be careful with this. For IE11:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15357/windows-internet-explorer-11-keyboard-shortcuts does not contain the string "cache"; the only reference to F5 is for "refresh page". I didn't recognize any other as equivalent to "refresh without cache". For Edge: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/13805/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-in-apps has an entry for "F5 or Ctrl+R" for "refresh page", but nothing I recognize as similar to "refresh without using cache".

Comment: For MS Edge: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/microsoft-edge-inprivate-mode/d6623fb7-db1a-4405-9977-d0e83750d7e7 says, "When you use InPrivate tabs or windows, your browsing data (like your history, temporary internet files, and cookies) isn't saved on your PC once you're done." From experience, it seems to load cache while in InPrivate. If you need to test without cache: At a minimum, it would seem you need to manually clear cache before each test. Maybe that'll work for you.

Comment: For MS Edge: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/microsoft-edge-inprivate-mode/d6623fb7-db1a-4405-9977-d0e83750d7e7 is an unresolved report of MS Edge InPrivate not working at all (2016). I've seen another such report; I didn't save that link.

Comment: For Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&ref_topic=7437824 says "Chrome won't save your browsing history, cookies and site data, or information entered in forms." https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7440301 says, " Cookies and site data are remembered while you're browsing, but deleted when you exit Incognito mode." So, like with MS Edge (above), if you need to test without cache: At a minimum, it would seem you need to manually clear cache before each test. Maybe that'll work for you.

Comment: For Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en includes an entry for "Shift + F5 or Ctrl + Shift + r" (Mac "⌘ + Shift + r") for "Reload your current page, ignoring cached content". I've had bad experience getting it to work. If I open a new tab, type CNN.com in the URL window, and touch Shift+F5, the URL window erases the request goes. If I type CNN.com again, then touch return (to paint CNN.com), then type HP.com, then touch Shift+F5, CNN.com paints again. Same for Ctrl+Shift+r. Further, I've noticed that if I "delete cache" and then do it again, some material remains.

Comment: Maybe Firefox will works perfectly; dunno. It's my primary browser and I don't care to delete cache. Anyone else care to report?

Answer (score 1):

You can do is press **ctrl + f5** or **ctrl + shift + r**.  You can also use "[Work  Offline](http://www.wikihow.com/Work-Offline-in-Mozilla-Firefox)" mode if your using Firefox.

Comment: Or "incognito"-mode (also known as porn-time) in Chrome (cmd+shift+r @ mac) / ctrl+shift+r @ windows)

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around this is to add a version to the css file that's the time it has been changed last:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime("path/style.css"); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively you could use a plugin that ultimately does the same thing: https://wordpress.org/plugins/stylecss-load-last-version/

Note: these are solutions that will always load the most recent css file for all. If you only want to test, use the solution of @user3085741 (refresh the page).

Comment: I am testing your solution. Of course I want more than just to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative when you are doing development would be to turn off caching in Firefox altogether:
"Hamburger menu"->Preferences->Advanced->Network.  Check the box that says "Override cache management" and limit the cache to 0 MB.

This way **no** pages will be cached in Firefox until you decide to turn caching back on (just uncheck the override box you checked above).

This won't help if something else is doing the caching, like a proxy or the server itself.

Hope this is helpful.